# Vitejs React This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: reactjs, vite

The server is running but found this "This localhost page can’t be found"
see attached images

Comment: Where are the attached images? Can you show a [mcve] of the code that caused this, [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vite Server is running but not working on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694187/vite-server-is-running-but-not-working-on-localhost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access https://localhost:4200 as your dev server listening this port. If you want to change 4200 port to 3000 you should be able to do it using flag `-p 3000`

Comment: thanks for your reply,
I try after changing port but still finding same issue
this project is running on one system but not running on mine

Comment: please show the command you run `vite` dev server with updated port

Comment: I use this
npm start ,
and also this
npm start-p 3000

Comment: but what command in your package.json for start script?

Comment: "start": "vite --https --port 4200"

Comment: you should change port here, in this command, like: "start": "vite --https --port 3000"