# Vite Server is running but not working on localhost

Tags: reactjs, vite

Vite + Reactjs server is running but I am getting
"This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:4200/"
on the browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vitejs React This localhost page can’t be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681314/vitejs-react-this-localhost-page-can-t-be-found)

Answer (score 31):

A common mistake when moving from create react app/react-scripts to Vite is having the `index.html` in the `public` folder.
Make sure your `index.html` file is in the root directory for your Vite project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 20):

Just in case someone is looking for a solution and the other answers didn't work, here is what worked for me.

In vite.config.js I had to set the host to '127.0.0.1' in the [server options](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host).

```
{
  server: {
    host: '127.0.0.1'
  }
}
```

The default value is localhost but why that doesn't work I still don't know...

Comment: I encountered this issue when using VSCode with the Remote-SSH extension for my Astro project. It worked fine if I logged into the remote box, but to access the dev server remotely I had to explicitly set host to '127.0.0.1'.

Apparently this is an issue with Vite-based projects and VSCode Remote-SSH: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8213

Comment: I encountered this issue after upgrading node version, Vite app couldn't be accessible via localhost though CRA app worked. This solution worked for me like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also if you run Vite in a node docker container host: '0.0.0.0' might help.

Answer (score 11):

TLDR: Change the Port

For me, it was that I already had something running on the port that Vite was trying to serve the app on (3000).

Doing a quick `lsof -nPi :3000` (MacOSX) I saw that my docker desktop was running on that port.

---

You can do this statically by updating a server key in the vite config (`vite.config.js`)

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 8000
  }
})
```

Or dynamically via the start command:
`vite --port 8000`

---

https://vitejs.dev/config/#config-file

Answer (score 6):

**Create a vite.js project and then edit the ***vite.config.js*** like this
(*it helps me to run the project on localhost*):**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue, but there was nothing using the port 3000, but anyways, I change it to `port 8000` and it's working

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react() tsconfigPaths()],
  server: {
    port: 8000
  }
});
```

Comment: changing port in config worked for me on macos. thanks

Comment: I'm on WSL and thought it was some weird issue with my environment. Nothing was running on 5173, but changing it worked for whatever reason. Thanks!

Comment: using ubuntu and it doesn't work on 5173
but works on 8000 :v

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it was related to the project folder name.
It had some spaces in the name of the project's folder.
I removed spaces and the node_module folder then I installed packages again, and now it's working fine.

Comment: yes, I have the same problem, I also just removed spaces from the folder name, and its works for me.

Comment: yep! I had cloned a repo from azure and the root directory had some special characters. After renaming the root folder name to a simple name, it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. click collapse your project structure in vscode, vite config file was not at the level of index.html. So make sure it should be at where index.html is, **Double check please!!**

Comment: This is the same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71096224/6243352). Maybe just upvote that rather than adding a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

My issue that happened to me that seems possible to commonly happen was I had another `index.html` file in my public dir. That file will take precedence over the one in your project root, so make sure you delete that or move it elsewhere. For me, it was a remnant of a `vite build` that I didn't notice hung around

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change any port or anything just a `--host` flag should do the work.

```
yarn dev --host
```

Make sure your firewall is disabled on the private (and sometimes domain also) network, and nodejs runtime is allowed in the firewall allowed apps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will be using

`vite start`, or

`vite run start`

Instead of these please run this:

`npm run dev`

or if you using yarn then

`yarn run dev`

This resolved my issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old to answer, but I fixed it using the command below.

**Use:**

`npm run dev -- --host`

**Instead of:**

`npm run dev --host`

Just add the double hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here helped me. It turns out uBlock Origin was preventing the `index.html` page from loading when accessing it through `localhost:3000`. Disabling it or trying it in incognito mode works!

Answer (score 0):

For me, beside server host true in the vitejs settings, I needed to update the docker run command with "--service-ports" (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/):

```
docker-compose -p myservice run --service-ports --rm node npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have a problem in your directory, make sure that the index.html is global, means not in any directory besides your project, and also make sure that the vite.config.js is on the same level as the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

In your `vite.config.js` file you can specify the value of `root` to direct to your `index.html` file. For example if your structure is `src/public/index.html'`, you would simply need to set `root: 'src/public'`

Answer (score 0):

You Just Have to cd into the src folder and then run npm run dev

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't have any of the issues the people above mention, it is also possible it will not run if you are working in a directory that has a space in its name like My%20Project%20 this will break vite server.

See this open issue - https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8904

Answer (score 0):

I think the vite localhost at default starts at localhost:5173, try this and see if it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  server: {
    allowedHosts: [".localhost"],
    host: true,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

just rename the html file to index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working with an extension and it is not working, consider removing `background.ts` from `manifest.json`. After that remove the extension and install it again